# Fit graph to colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have an imshow graph that shows a colobar for numerical values. The colorbar is much bigger than the graph. Is there a way to scale them so they end up the same size, preferably without affecting the aspect ratio of the graph?

```
grid = np.ma.array(grid, mask=np.isnan(grid))
plot.imshow(grid, interpolation='nearest', aspect='equal', vmax = private.vmax, vmin = private.vmin)
plot.minorticks_off()
plot.set_xticks(range(len(placex)))        
plot.set_yticks(range(len(placey)))
plot.set_xticklabels(placex)        
plot.set_yticklabels(placey, rotation = 0)
plot.colorbar()
plot.show()
```

Comment: what is the aspect ratio of the graph?  Can you tweak your code to either include enough constants (`placey`, `private.*`, etc) so that other people can run your code via copy and paste?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify an axes-object by any of the built-in methods of matplotlib and then use it for your colorbar, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,6), (0, 5), colspan=1)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,6), (0, 0), colspan=5)


plt.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
plt.colorbar(cax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

This will result in something like:

[image: Plot of sample code]

Though, this doesn't help if your imshow-axes becomes very flat (due to `aspect="equal"`, this might happen).

If you want to handle such cases, you can either

1. Adjust the figure size to the aspect of your grid, e.g.

   ```
    fig = figure(figsize=grid.shape[1]*1.5/dpi, grid.shape[0]/dpi)
   ```
2. Read the coordinates of ax1 AFTER plotting, create ax2 just after that with the appropriately transformed coordinates and then use ax2 for the colorbar. This doesn't behave nicely when you resize the window, but might work out if you just create plots as image files automatically.

If 2. is what you need, I can add an example for this, but I will only do this work if you are sure this is what you want.

Greetings,
Thorsten